# JavaScript Breakout Game

Tags: javascript, beginner, game, animation, canvas

I'm a novice programmer who is very new to JavaScript, and animation/graphics, and I have this breakout game on my flask website.

I tried to do as much as I could from scratch, and I'm unsure if my physics system and especially collision detection are done reasonably well. I get little collision bugs sometimes (a block not being removed from the list although the ball bounces properly, or ball bouncing through a block instead of bouncing off it). It seems to have more trouble running in Firefox. Advice on general coding issues is of course welcome as well.

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="game">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="1000" height="700" style="border:1px solid black;">
    </canvas>
</div>
<script>
    (function() { // from https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671
        var lastTime = 0;
        var vendors = ['webkit', 'moz'];
        for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
            window.cancelAnimationFrame =
            window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
        }
        if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
            window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
                var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); },
                timeToCall);
                lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                return id;
            }
        if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
            window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
                clearTimeout(id);
            }
    }());

    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var blocks = [];
    var mousepos;
    var paddle;
    var balls = [];
    var queueballs = [];
    var maxspeed = 10;
    var lasttime;
    var pause = false;
    var currentlevel = 0;
    var levels = [];
    var powerups = [];
    var activepowerups = [];
    var bullets = 0;
    var lastshot;
    var firedbullets = [];
    window.onblur = function() {pause = true;}
    window.onfocus = function() {
        lasttime = null; // prevent physics bugs on refocus
        pause = false;
    }
    function setCookie(cookiename, cookievalue) {
        var dt = new Date();
        dt.setFullYear(dt.getFullYear() + 1);
        document.cookie = cookiename + "=" + cookievalue + ";expires=" + dt
    }
    function animate(time) {
        var timedif;
        if (!lasttime) {
            lasttime = time;
            timedif = 1;
        } else {
            timedif = (time - lasttime) / 20;
            lasttime = time;
            if (timedif > 2) {timedif = 1}; // trying to prevent lag from killing the physics
        }
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        drawGame(timedif);
    }
    function drawGame(time) {
        updatePhysics(time);
        updatePaddle();
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        for (var i=0;i<blocks.length;i++) {
            blocks[i].creator();
        }
        paddle.creator();
        if (queueballs.length > 0) {
            var qball = queueballs[queueballs.length - 1]
            qball.x = paddle.x + paddle.width / 2;
            qball.y = paddle.y - qball.radius;
            qball.vector = [0, 0];
            qball.creator();
        }
        for (var i=0;i<balls.length;i++) {
            balls[i].creator();
        }
        for (var i=0;i<activepowerups.length;i++) {
            activepowerups[i].creator();
        }
        for (var i=0; i<firedbullets.length;i++) {
            firedbullets[i].creator();
        }
        if (bullets > 0) {
            if (!lastshot) {
                lastshot = new Date().getTime();
                fireBullet();
            } else {
                var now = new Date().getTime()
                if (now - lastshot > 750) {
                    lastshot = now;
                    fireBullet();
                }
            }
        }
        ctx.font = "80px Arial";
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.fillText(queueballs.length + balls.length,25,680);
        if (balls.length + queueballs.length == 0) {loseGame();}
        else if (blocks.length == 0) {winGame();}
    }
    function winGame() {
        currentlevel += 1;
        if (currentlevel >= levels.length) {currentlevel = 0;alert("You win!");}
        setCookie("breakout", currentlevel);
        balls = [];
        queueballs = [];
        activepowerups = [];
        bullets = 0;
        levels[currentlevel]();
    }
    function loseGame() {
        blocks = [];
        bullets = 0;
        activepowerups = [];
        levels[currentlevel]();
    }
    function mouseClick() {
        if (queueballs.length > 0) {
            balls.push(queueballs.pop());
            balls[balls.length - 1].vector = [4, -4];
        }
    }
    function updatePhysics(time) {
        if (pause) {return;}
        for (var i=0;i<blocks.length;i++) {
            var vector = blocks[i].vector;
            blocks[i].x = blocks[i].x + vector[0];
            blocks[i].y = blocks[i].y + vector[1];
        }
        for (var i=0;i<balls.length;i++) {
            var vector = balls[i].vector;
            balls[i].x = balls[i].x + vector[0] * time;
            balls[i].y = balls[i].y + vector[1] * time;
            checkCollision(balls[i]);
            if (balls[i].y > paddle.y + paddle.height) {
                balls.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<activepowerups.length;i++) {
            var vector = activepowerups[i].vector;
            activepowerups[i].x += vector[0] * time;
            activepowerups[i].y += vector[1] * time;
            if (checkPowCatch(activepowerups[i])) {
                activepowerups.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<firedbullets.length;i++) {
            var vector = firedbullets[i].vector;
            firedbullets[i].x += vector[0] * time;
            firedbullets[i].y += vector[1] * time;
            if (checkBulletHit(firedbullets[i])) {
                firedbullets.splice(i, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    function updatePaddle() {
        paddle.x = mousepos? mousepos.x - (paddle.width/2) : paddle.x;
    }
    function checkCollision(obj) {
        if (obj.x - obj.radius <= 0) {obj.vector = [Math.abs(obj.vector[0]), obj.vector[1]];}; // wall collisions
        if (obj.y - obj.radius <= 0) {obj.vector = [obj.vector[0], Math.abs(obj.vector[1])]}
        if (obj.y + obj.radius >= canvas.height) {obj.vector = [obj.vector[0], -Math.abs(obj.vector[1])]}
        if (obj.x + obj.radius >= canvas.width) {obj.vector = [-Math.abs(obj.vector[0]), obj.vector[1]]}
        if (obj.y > paddle.y - obj.radius && obj.y < paddle.y + paddle.height / 2) { // paddle collision
            if (obj.vector[1] > 0 && obj.x + obj.radius / 2 > paddle.x && obj.x - obj.radius / 2 < paddle.x + paddle.width) {
                var vector = obj.vector;
                var angle = (paddle.x + paddle.width / 2) - obj.x;
                if (Math.abs(angle) < 15) {angle = 0}
                var yvector = vector[1] < maxspeed? -(vector[1] + 0.6) : -vector[1];
                obj.vector = [vector[0] - angle / 10, yvector];
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<blocks.length;i++) { // block collision
            if (checkClose(obj, blocks[i])) {
                var quad = checkQuadrant(obj, blocks[i]);
                if (checkHit(obj, blocks[i], quad)) {
                    checkPowerup(blocks[i]);
                    blocks.splice(i, 1);
                    bounce(obj, quad);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    function checkPowCatch(obj) {
        if (obj.y > paddle.y - obj.radius && obj.y < paddle.y + paddle.height / 2) { // paddle collision
            if (obj.vector[1] > 0 && obj.x + obj.radius / 2 > paddle.x && obj.x - obj.radius / 2 < paddle.x + paddle.width) {
                obj.power();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    function checkBulletHit(obj) {
        for (var i=0;i<blocks.length;i++) {
            if (obj.x + 4 >= blocks[i].x && obj.x <= blocks[i].x + blocks[i].width && obj.y < blocks[i].y + blocks[i].height) {
                blocks.splice(i, 1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    function checkHit(obj, block, quadrant) {
        if (quadrant == "top" || quadrant == "bottom") {
            var y = quadrant == "top" ? block.y : block.y + block.height;
            for (var x=block.x;x<block.x + block.width;x++) {
                if (checkDistance(x, y, obj.x, obj.y) <= obj.radius) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        } else {
            var x = quadrant == "left" ? block.x : block.x + block.width;
            for (var y=block.y;y<block.y + block.height;y++) {
                if (checkDistance(x, y, obj.x, obj.y) <= obj.radius) {
                    return true
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    function bounce (obj, quadrant) {
        var vector = obj.vector;
        if (quadrant == "bottom") {
            obj.vector = [vector[0], Math.abs(vector[1])];
        } else if (quadrant == "top") {
            obj.vector = [vector[0], -Math.abs(vector[1])];
        } else if (quadrant == "right") {
            obj.vector = [Math.abs(vector[0]), vector[1]];
        } else {
            obj.vector = [-Math.abs(vector[0]), vector[1]];
        }
    }
    function checkClose(ball, block) {
        blockcenter = [block.x + block.width / 2, block.y + block.height / 2];
        centertoedge = checkDistance(block.x, block.y, blockcenter[0], blockcenter[1]);
        if (checkDistance(ball.x, ball.y, blockcenter[0], blockcenter[1]) < centertoedge + ball.radius) {
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
    function checkDistance(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) + Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
    }
    function checkQuadrant(ball, block) {
        var top = block.y;
        var bottom = block.y + block.height;
        var left = block.x;
        var right = block.x + block.width;
        if (ball.y > bottom && ball.x < block.x + block.width / 2) { // bottom left side
            var b = left + bottom;
            if (ball.y > -1 * ball.x + b) {return "bottom"}; // check line y > -1*x + b
            return "left";
        }
        else if (ball.y > bottom) { // bottom right side
            var b = bottom - right;
            if (ball.y < ball.x + b) {return "right"}; // check line y > x + b
            return "bottom";
        }
        else if (ball.y < top && ball.x < block.x + block.width / 2) { // top left side
            var b = top - left;
            if (ball.y > ball.x + b) {return "left"}
            return "top";
        }
        else if (ball.y < top) { // top right side
            var b = top + right;
            if (ball.y < -1 * ball.x + b) {return "top"}
            return "right"
        }
        else if (ball.x > right) { // right side
            return "right"
        }
        else if (ball.x < left) { // left side
            return "left"
        }
    }
    function checkPowerup(block) {
        if (Math.random() * 30 > 29) {
            var pow = Math.round(Math.random() * (powerups.length - 1));
            powerups[pow](block.x + block.width / 2, block.y + block.height / 2);
        }
    }
    function getPosition(e, istouch) {
        var xoffset = 0;
        var yoffset = 0;
        if (!e)
            e = window.event;
        var main = document.getElementById("main");
        var game = document.getElementById("game");
        xoffset += canvas.offsetLeft;
        yoffset += canvas.offsetTop;
        if (istouch) {
            e = e.changedTouches[0];
        }
        var x = e.pageX - xoffset;
        var y = e.pageY - yoffset;
        return {"x": x, "y": y}
    }
    canvas.onmousemove = function(event) {
        mousepos = getPosition(event);
    }
    canvas.ontouchmove = function (event) {
        mousepos = getPosition(event, true);
    }
    canvas.onclick = function () {
        mouseClick();
    }
    function rect(x, y, w, h, vector, creator, ispaddle) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.width = w;
        this.height = h;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.creator = function() {creator(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height)}
        if (!ispaddle) {blocks.push(this);}
    }
    function circle(x, y, r, vector, creator, noque) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = r;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.creator = function() {creator(this.x, this.y, this.radius)}
        if (!noque) {queueballs.push(this);}
    }
    var redRect = function(x, y, w, h) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
    var blueRect = function(x, y, w, h) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
    var yellowBall = function(x, y, r) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.arc(x, y, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
        ctx.fill()
    }
    function powerup(x, y, radius, vector, creator, power) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.creator = function() {creator(this.x, this.y)};
        this.power = power;
        activepowerups.push(this);
    }
    var splitballpower = function () {
        if (balls.length == 0) {
            balls.push(new circle(paddle.x + paddle.width / 2, paddle.y - 20, 20, [4, -4], yellowBall, true));
            return;
        }
        var lastball = balls[balls.length - 1];
        balls.push(new circle(lastball.x, lastball.y, 20, [4, -4], yellowBall, true));
        balls.push(new circle(lastball.x, lastball.y, 20, [4, 4], yellowBall, true));
        balls.push(new circle(lastball.x, lastball.y, 20, [-4, -4], yellowBall, true));
        balls.push(new circle(lastball.x, lastball.y, 20, [-4, 4], yellowBall, true));
    }
    var splitball = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x,y,7,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x-6,y-10,7,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x+6,y-10,7,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
    }
    powerups.push(function(x, y) {
        new powerup(x, y, 15, [0, 3], splitball, splitballpower)
    });
    function bullet(x, y, vector, creator) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.vector = vector;
        this.creator = function() {creator(this.x, this.y)};
        firedbullets.push(this);
    }
    var crbullet = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 4, 15);
    }
    function fireBullet() {
        new bullet(paddle.x + paddle.width / 2 - 2, paddle.y, [0, -15], crbullet);
        bullets -= 1;
    }
    var gunpower = function () {
        bullets += 15;
    }
    var gunpowerup = function(x, y) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "blue";
        ctx.fillRect(x - 13, y - 5, 26, 10);
        ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        ctx.fillRect(x - 1, y - 12, 2, 7);
    }
    powerups.push(function(x, y) {
        new powerup(x, y, 15, [0, 4], gunpowerup, gunpower)
    });
    function level0() {
        maxspeed = 10;
        for (var q=0;q<3;q++) {
            for (var i=1;i<21;i++) {
                var block = new rect(50 + (i * 41), 50 + (q * 21), 40, 20, [0, 0], redRect);
            }
        }
        var ball = new circle(200, 400, 30, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        for (var i=0;i<2;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 20, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 100, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level0);
    function level1() {
        maxspeed = 10;
        for (var i=0;i<40;i++) {
            var block = new rect(Math.round(Math.random() * 900), Math.round(Math.random() * 500), 40, 20, [0, 0], redRect);
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 20, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 100, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level1);
    function level2() {
        maxspeed = 10;
        var alt = false;
        for (var q=0;q<8;q++) {
            for (var i=1;i<22;i++) {
                if (alt) {
                    alt = false;
                    continue;
                } else {alt = true;}
                var block = new rect(30 + (i * 41), 50 + (q * 21), 40, 20, [0, 0], redRect);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 20, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        var ball = new circle(200, 400, 10, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 100, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level2);
    function level3() {
        maxspeed = 10;
        for (var q=0;q<4;q++) {
            for (var i=1;i<21;i++) {
                var block = new rect(50 + (i * 41), 50 + (q * 42), 40, 20, [0, 0], redRect);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 10, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 70, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level3);
    function level4() {
        maxspeed = 10;
        for (var i=0;i<60;i++) {
            var block = new rect(Math.round(Math.random() * 900), Math.round(Math.random() * 500), 60, 30, [0, 0], redRect);
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 30, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 100, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level4);
    function level5() {
        maxspeed = 20;
        for (var q=0;q<8;q++) {
            for (var i=1;i<21;i++) {
                if (Math.random() * 3 > 2) {continue;}
                var block = new rect(50 + (i * 41), 50 + (q * 31), 40, 20, [0, 0], redRect);
            }
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            var ball = new circle(200, 400, 20, [0, 0], yellowBall);
        }
        paddle = new rect(400, 600, 80, 30, [0, 0], blueRect, true);
    }
    levels.push(level5);
    var cookie = document.cookie.split("; ");
    for (i=0;i<cookie.length;i++) {
        var cooki = cookie[i].split("=");
        if (cooki[0] == "breakout") {currentlevel = parseInt(cooki[1]);}
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    levels[currentlevel]();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I wouldn't worry about the polyfill. Browsers that do support [`<canvas>`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=canvas) also support [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=requestanimationframe). `<canvas>`, being older, came earlier and there is a slight period where you may have `<canvas>` but not `requestAnimationFrame`. But most users probably won't be using browsers that old anymore.

Your game could benefit using a game engine or even just a canvas drawing library. Canvas uses [immediate-mode rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_mode_(computer_graphics)). It's like paint. You apply, there's no turning back unless you spill white and start over. Libraries abstract this away from you and make it look like [retained mode rendering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retained_mode). You define the state of an object, and the library takes care of everything else. It's much easier when all you know is you have a box at position and it just renders.

Now I'm not going going to review the entire code. Most likely you'll throw this code away in favor of a library or engine. I'll just nitpick a few notable things.

One thing I learned from game engines is that instead of using time elapsed between frames to compensate for framerate, what they do is provide a scaling factor instead. This can be calculated by `actual time elapsed / one frame at 60fps`.

```
// At 60fps, your ball would have moved 60 units, but at 40fps, only 40.
// 60fps * 1unit = 60units
// 40fps * 1unit = 40units
ballPosition = ballPosition + 1;

// With a scaling factor, 40fps would have a 3/2 factor compensating the lag
// 25ms / 16.6ms ~ 1.5
// 40fps * (1unit * 1.5) = 60units
ballPosition = (ballPosition + 1) * scale;
```

The advantage of using a scaling factor is that the scale is unitless. Your equation can be written without anticipating a value that has a unit, like say time. You can simply write the equation as is, and multiply the scale.

I see that your code is clearing arrays by assigning new arrays. What you could do instead of creating another array is to set the `length` of the existing array to `0`. This will empty the array without making another array. Just make sure there's nothing else referencing the elements in the array for the GC to pick them up.

```
var foo = [1,2,3];
foo.length = 0;
foo // []
```

Another cause of performance issues in JS is when you [keep altering the size of an array](https://gamealchemist.wordpress.com/2013/05/01/lets-get-those-javascript-arrays-to-work-fast/), like using `splice`. What you could do is create a fixed-size array, and if you need to remove the item, have it marked as removed rather than removing it.

Constructor names usually have the convention of having the first letter of a word in capital letters. So `rect`, `circle` and others should be `Rect`, `Circle` etc.

Consider using factories instead of constructors. Factories are just functions that return objects. Constructors are usually overkill in your case because they do all the work of hooking up a prototype object but your code doesn't appear to use inheritance or method sharing. Also, the only method you have for these objects is `creator` which is just like a factory with a closure around it.

```
function createCircle(x, y, radius, vector) {
  // The following is ES6 shorthand literal notation
  return {x, y, radius, vector};
}
```

I would also advise that you put the responsibility of pushing the objects into an array to the caller. Don't make it implicit that they get pushed to a queue. If necessary, create a function that creates circles *and* pushes them in a queue and named appropriately for the operation.